# use database entries as links to show details from db on a a page

Tags: html, oracle, jsp

```
<%
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@VAIO:1521:XE","system","manager");
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("Select * from tasks");
ResultSet rset=stmt.executeQuery();
while(rset.next())
{
%>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href=""><%out.print(rset.getString(2));%></a>
</td>
<td>
<%out.print(rset.getString(3));%>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<%
}
%>
```

Need to use all entries of the table as hyperlinks to open on a new page with other details from the database. any idea how to do so?

Comment: Yes and quite a lot of them. Want us to write a code for you? You must show, what you already tried, what output did you get and why it does not suit you.

Comment: I am new to programming. I have a huge db and 2nd column of my db is displayed. If it gets clicked, i want to display that particular row of the table on a new page. How do i do dat?

Comment: @Saurabh On a different note, do not use `system` schema for user defined objects. Schemas like `system`, `sys` etc is normally used for database related objects and it must not be used for user defined objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a link to some detail servlet, with a parameter indicating the ID of the row to display:

```
<a href="detailServlet?id=<%= rs.getLong(1) %>"><%out.print(rset.getString(2));%></a>
```

In the servlet, use request.getParameter("id") to get the ID sent by the link.

That said, you should not

- execute database access code from a JSP. JSPs should only generate HTML, using Java Beans stored in the request by a controller servlet
- use scriptlets. Learn to use the JSP EL, the JSTL and custom tags.

Using scriptlets and accessing the database from JSP is considered bad practice for more than 10 years. I really don't understand how newbies are still teached to do that. Good code would look like:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${rows}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="<c:url value="/detailServlet">
                         <c:param name="id" value="${row.id}"/
                     </c:url>"<c:out value="${row.name}"/></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <c:out value="${row.description}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i have no idea about jstl and stuffs. Just started with jsp's